# Should I use the CString::ReleaseBuffer() if I don't change the string size

Tags: buffer, c-strings

I have CString and I want to change some chars in buffer (I want to replace national chars (eg. á to a).
I change (in "for" loop) single charakters, but don't change string length.
Do I need to call CString::ReleaseBuffer()?